Solving $f(x) = f(\frac{a + b x}{c + d x}) = f(\frac{a' + b' x}{c' + d' x})$?
How to solve the equation
$$f(x) = f(\frac{a x + b}{c x + d}) = f(\frac{a'x + b'}{c'x + d'})$$
For given real $a,a',b,b',c,c',d,d'$ ?
Maybe this system of equations is a bit overdetermined in its general case.
In particular I assume the iterations of the linear fractional transformation should be periodic.
So of the type $v - x$, $w/x$ (period 2) or
$\frac{a x + b}{c x + d}$ with $ad - bc$ not $0$ and
$$\frac{(a+d)^2}{ad - bc} = 4 \cos^2(\frac{k \pi}{m}) $$
for some integer $k$ with (integer) period $m$.
I assume both periods of the linear fractional transformations should be equal ?
In fact I assume only period $2$ makes sense ?
I was able to find at least one solution
$$f(x) = f(\frac{1}{x}) = f(1-x)$$
$$f(x) = \frac{(x^2 - x + 1)^3}{x^2 (x-1)^2}$$
or more generally
$$f(x) = g(\frac{(x^2 - x + 1)^3}{x^2 (x-1)^2})$$
for any meromorphic function $g(x)$.
where both iterations are periodic with period $2$.
But I assume I am missing alot of ideas.
